# Error in fit.variogram.gls method of gstat package in R

Tags: r, variogram, gstat

I was trying to fit the variogram parameters of an empirical variogram using GLS (Generalized Least Squares) fitting method. I used the 'fit.variogram.gls' method of the 'gstat' package in R.
I tried it out by running the example code given in the help document.

library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
fit.variogram.gls(log(zinc)~1, meuse[1:40,], vgm(1, "Sph", 900,1))

But I was receiving the following error on running the above code :
**Error in gamfn(h0, theta) : could not find function "gamfn"**.

How do I go about interpreting the error and the remedy for it.

Answer (score 1):

This was reported as https://github.com/edzer/gstat/issues/33 and fixed at source. Before a new release becomes available, you need to install the package from source:

`library(devtools)
install_github("edzer/gstat")`